# How to write a CSV file with ANSI encoding using Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a problem with creating CSV file with data from my mongoDB. I am using fast-csv. Data is writing on Ukrainian it is why instead of 'Чоловік' I see 'пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ'. (Several patients are already present in the database)

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const updateRouter = require('./update-router');
const fs = require('fs');
const fastcsv = require('fast-csv');
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');
const app = express();
//-----------------------------------------------------
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use('/updatepage', updateRouter);
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.method + " : " + req.url);
  next();
});
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

//-----------------------------------------------------

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://admin-vlad:VP25102001VP@hospitalproject.cxdut.mongodb.net/hospital', {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});

const patientsSchema = {
  historyOfPatient: {
    type: Number,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  surnameOfPatient: String,
  nameOfPatient: String,
  midnameOfPatient: String,
  genderOfPatient: String,
  dateOfBirthday: String,
  dateOfBirthdayForUpdate: String,
  ageOfPatient: Number,
  ageGroupOfPatient: String,
  addressofPatient: String,
  dateOfArriving: String,
  dateOfArrivingForSearching: Date,
  dateOfArrivingForUpdate: String,
  dateOfBeingFree: String,
  dateOfBeingFreeForUpdate: String,
  bedDayOfPatient: String,
  extraHospitalOfPatient: String,
  sickTimeOfPatient: String,
  pibOfDocOfPatient: String,
  rezultOfreatmentOfPatient: String,
  ripDateOfPatient: String,
  mainDiagnosisOfPatient: String,
  mkxDiagnosisOfPatient: String,
  complicationOfPatient: String,
  сoncomitantDiagnosisOfPatient: String,
  surgeryOfPatient: String,
  laparoscopicSurgeryOfPatient: String,
  nameOfSurgeryOfPatient: String,
  dateOfSurgeryOfPatient: String,
  dateOfSurgeryOfPatientForUpdate: String,
  surgeryDoctorOfPatient: String,
  firstAssistantOfPatient: String,
  secondAssistantOfPatient: String,
  beforeSurgeryOfPatient: Number,
  afterSurgeryOfPatient: Number,
  typeOfSurgeryOfPatient: String,
  sumSurgeryOfPatient: String,
  nameOfSumSurgeryOfPatient: String,
  typeOfSumSurgeryOfPatient: String,
  complicationAfterSurgeryOfPatient: String,
  typeOfComplicationOfPatient: String,
  anotherTypeOfComplicationOfPatient: String

};

const Patient = mongoose.model("Patient", patientsSchema);

app.post("/findAll", function(req, res) {
  Patient.find({}, function(err, foundP) {
    if (!err) {
      if (foundP != null) {

        const ws = fs.createWriteStream("public/files/ListOfPatients.csv");
        let headers = Object.keys(Patient.schema.paths)
          .filter(k => ['_id', '__v', 'dateOfBirthdayForUpdate', 'dateOfArrivingForSearching',
            'dateOfArrivingForUpdate', 'dateOfBeingFreeForUpdate', 'dateOfSurgeryOfPatientForUpdate'
          ].indexOf(k) === -1);

        console.log(headers);

        fastcsv.write(foundP, {headers}).on("finish", function() {
          console.log("Write to ListOfPatients.csv successfully!");
        }).pipe(ws);

        res.render("find", {
          foundPat: foundP
        });
        console.log(foundP);
      }
    }
  });

});

//------------------------------------------------------
let port = process.env.PORT;
if (port == null || port == "") {
  port = 3000;
}
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Server has started successfully");
});
```

Also I was trying to use iconv for only one field to see if it is work:

```
fastcsv.write(foundP.map(item => {
          console.log(item.genderOfPatient);
         return {
          ...item,
          genderOfPatient: iconv.encode(item.genderOfPatient,'win1251')
        }}), {
          headers
        }).on("finish", function() {
          console.log("Write to ListOfPatients.csv successfully!");
        }).pipe(ws);
```

Even attribute charset="windows-1252" in download button doesn't help:

```
<a href="files/ListOfPatients.csv" charset="windows-1252" class="form-btn" download="ListOfPatients.csv"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Excel</button></a>
```

Comment: Win1252 does not support Ukrainian

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit so how can I solve my problem?

Comment: [Windows-1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) may work. Note, MongoDB internaly uses only UTF-8, so you have to convert your data in any case.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I tried to do like this:                                                                        fastcsv.write( encoding.convert(foundP, 'WINDOWS-1251', 'UTF-8')
          , {
            headers
          }).on("finish", function() {
          console.log("Write to ListOfPatients.csv successfully!");
        }).pipe(ws);                                                                                                                   In the console I can see that the conversion was successful, but now it does not enter this data in the file